# Rendering rails template in variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

How can I get Rails ApplicationController.render to render a template in variable instead of sending it back to browser? Basically what I am trying to do is to prepare an email content in my controller by making a template in views file with locals and then rendering the template by passing locals in variable which will be set as content of email.

Comment: `render_to_string` might help you. But why aren't you just using ActionMailer?

Comment: I am working on a project and they are using MailGun Service